# Java: NoClassDefFoundError in maven project?

Tags: java, render, lwjgl, display

I've started developing a 3D java game engine using OpenGL in Codenvy IDE, using Maven. I've configured to run Java 8, and I've set up the dependencies in `pom.xml` that is required for `LWJGL`. However, when I run a test window, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I'm unsure why this happens, considering `Maven` is configured to store all `.Jar` dependencies into one filem so accessing them shouldn't be a concern. All the files have downloaded properly into the `External Packages` directory in my Codenvy project.

Here is the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>engineTester.First3DEngine</groupId>
   <artifactId>First3DEngine</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.7</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
      <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
      <artifactId>lwjgl_util</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
      <artifactId>lwjgl_util_applet</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
      <artifactId>slick_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>java3d</groupId>
      <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>engineTester.MainGameLoop</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

And here is where I'm getting the issue:

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;
import util.Console;

public class MainGameLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Console();
        DisplayManager.createDisplay();  <-- line which throws the error
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            //game logic
            //render
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

    }
}
```

`DisplayManager.createDisplay()` method:

```
public static void createDisplay(){
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2);
    attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
    attribs.withProfileCore(true);

    try{
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
    } catch (LWJGLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GL11.glViewport(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}
```

And finally the full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well clearly the classes from LWJGL or not actually on the runtime classpath, so apparently something in the jar export is not happening as you expect it to happen. The maven jar plugin is not going to create a fat jar like you are expecting. Open up the generated jar in a zip tool and see for yourself.

Comment: @Gimby so how would i go about setting the `.jar` files to be on the runtime classpath? Using `<scope></scope>`?

Comment: What maven goals are you running? AFAIK, that jar plugin configuration will not actually do anything unless you configure an execution (or explicitly call a jar-plugin goal).

Comment: @rmlan sorry i do not understand. I'm relatively new to this, could you explain?

Comment: When you type the `mvn` command on the command-line, what goals are you typing after `mvn`? For example: `mvn clean install`.

Comment: @rmlan i dont type anything in the command line. I'm using Codenvy IDE, i just build the jar file/edit the pom. There is no maven command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use maven-assembly-plugin to make a fat jar that can be run by itself or you can run your program using maven so that the compile time jars will be added to your classpath.

To run using maven:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="engineTester.MainGameLoop"
```

To use the assembly plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>engineTester.MainGameLoop</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This will create a jar with `-jar-with-depencencies` added to the name in the target directory. That can then just be run with java -jar jarfile.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however the issue seems to be that I can't actually control/i dont know ho to control how maven executes. There isn't a terminal in which i can type `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="engineTester.MainGameLoop"`, as i'm using codenvy IDE (which is a cloud based IDE, used in browser and is emtirely independant to system variables). So how would i go about this for Codenvy?

Comment: Sorry, I never used CodeEnvy before. Looking at it theoretically one could run some maven commands with the Build -> Custom Maven Build .. and others by replacing the CMD in the runner properties file with a maven command but in my tests both seem extremely limited/problematic.  For this kind of application it would seem to me much easier to develop with a desktop IDE or just running maven and a text editor on your own computer. If you really have to use CodeEnvy, using the assembly plugin is probably your best bet.